# Python: How to create an object with expandable numpy array members

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following use case:

1. I am receiving 100 samples per second of several numpy nd-arrays, say `a` of shape `(4, 3)`, and `b` of shape `(5, 6)`.
2. On other instances, I could be receiving `c` of shape `(2, 3)`, and `d` of shape `(3, 5)` and `e` of some other shape, and so on.
3. These samples arrive for some variable time between a single sample and 360000 samples (an hour).
4. **I would like to treat an entire streaming session as an object**

---

I would like to have something like

```
class Aggregator_ab(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.a = ???
        self.b = ???

    def add_sample(new_a, new_b):
        self.a.update(new_a)  # How can I achieve such an update?
        self.b.update(new_b)  # How can I achieve such an update?
```

Now, I would like to

access `Aggregator_ab`'s fields as numpy arrays:

```
agg = Aggregator_ab()  # maybe with parameters?

num_samples = 4

for i in range(num_samples):
    agg.add_sample(new_a=np.zeros((4, 3), new_b=np.zeros((5, 6))

assert agg.a.shape[0] == num_samples 
assert agg.b.shape[0] == num_samples 
assert agg.a.shape[1:] == (4, 3)
assert agg.b.shape[1:] == (5, 6)
```

And I would also expect regular numpy behavior of the members of `agg`.

---

My current code has some problems, and looks something like:

```
class Aggregator_ab(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.__as = []
        self.__bs = []

    def add_sample(new_a, new_b):
        self.__as.append(new_a)
        self.__bs.append(new_b)

    @property
    def a(self):
        return np.vstack(self.__as)

    @property
    def b(self):
        return np.vstack(self.__bs)
```

problems:

1. can only get a "full" numpy array after using `vstack`
2. must use expensive `vstack` every "get"
3. can't utilize previous `vstacks`
4. adding any field requires a lot of boilerplate which I would like to extract
5. This only supports very limited use cases, and If i ever want something more, I would have to implement myself.
6. going through native python lists is the only way to scale the array size without paying too much for resizing. Had I used vstack to keep a numpy array, at large sizes, I wouldn't be able to keep up with the frame rate.

---

This seems to me like a common use case, thus I believe someone has solved this before me.

**Is there some library that does this?** I know pandas sounds right, but what do I do if I have fields that are matrices?

If not, then how is this usually dealt with?

Answer (score 0):

What about allocating an array that keeps growing in size? It works like vectors in most common languages:

```
import numpy as np
class growing_array:
    def __init__(self, shape, growth):
        self._arr=np.empty(shape=(*shape, growth))
        self.incoming_shape=shape
        self.num_entries=0
        self.growth=growth

    def append(self, incoming_arr):
        if self.num_entries == self._arr.shape[2]:
            self._arr.resize(*self.incoming_shape, self._arr.shape[2]+self.growth)
        self._arr[:,:,self.num_entries] = incoming_arr
        self.num_entries+=1

    def get(self):
        return self._arr[:,:,0:self.num_entries]
```

Comment: This would cause 30000+ element copies (let alone re-alloc) EVERY UPDATE (100 times per sec). this is not feasable

Comment: If you set growth to e.g. 1000 this will not realloc on every append, and there will only be 2x3 so 6 element copies on every append

Comment: on my machine (standard desktop pc) using slices from another array it takes about 800ms for 10E6 appends when using growth=1000